# Laravel get record from table

Tags: php, laravel

I have table attributes.

I have columns:

- id
- name
- bind_id

I have model attribute and I want do attributeRelated with return collection attribute with bind_id. How I can do it?

```
public function getRelatedAttribute()
{
    return $this->where('id', $this->bind_attribute);
}
```

not working. I get error undifined object.

Comment: can you post full model code?

Comment: You mean getting attributes with specific bind_id?

Comment: yes. Of course .

Answer (score 0):

The statement to get all related attributes if your model name is Attributes would be

```
Attributes::where('bind_id' ,$your_desired_value)->get();
```

If the function is in the model class you can do this in the function:

```
return $this->where('bind_id',$your_desired_value)->get();
```